# Making d3 v4 group react to simulation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**jsfiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/z7ju3z1q/3/

The problem is, I can't make titles stick with groups with working simulation.
Changing line 76 from simulation.nodes(nodes); to simulation.nodes(node); breaks simulation (apparently), but makes title stick to circles. As I understand, the problem is that dragging working with circles but not with groups, for some reason. And that's is the problem Iwe been facing whole day.

I tried describing title like this (line 38)

```
var title = g.selectAll("text");
```

And then adding it to tick (line 84)

```
function ticked() {
    title.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understand, the problem is that dragging working with circles but not with groups, for some reason

You are manipulating the nodes on drag with cx and cy properties. `g` elements do not have these, so this will not achieve what you want, even if `node` contained groups rather than circles:

```
  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
```

As noted,`node = g.append("circle")` means that you aren't actually manipulating the `g` elements anyways, which is why your circles move on tick or drag.

Instead, keep node a selection of `g` elements, and manipulate the `transform` property:

```
  // the group representing each node:
  node = node.enter().append("g").merge(node);

  // the circle for each group
  node.append("circle")
  .classed('node', true).attr('id', id)
  .text(id)
  .attr("r", 25).attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.id); });

  // the text for each group
  node.append("text")
  .classed('text', true)
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .attr("dx", 6).text(id).merge(node);
```

Then, on click or drag events, just update the transform:

Tick:

```
  node.attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")" ;});
```

Drag:

```
  d.x = d3.event.x;
  d.y = d3.event.y;
  d3.select(this).attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")" ;});
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyg8nkgb/).

Comment: That does it. Thank you, Andrew! Edits are minor, but I just couldn't wrap my head around it.